# Trouble importing Twitter API on Jupyter/ipython notebook

Tags: twitter, ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am new to Jupyter/ipython notebook and working with API's in general. I am trying to import the Twitter API.

I want to import the twitter api, but all I am getting is:

"module not found"

error when I type:

import twitter

and run the code. How do you import something like Twitter's API to your Jupyter notebook? I already have O-Auth registerd. Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed the module?  What OS are you working in?

Comment: The key here is not only to have it installed, but to have it installed in the same interpreter that also starts the jupyter kernel.

Comment: I did not correctly install the module, thank you!